# How to restart Alcatel-Lucent OmniSwitch 9600

Tags: boot, telnet, alcatel-lucent

I need to restart/reboot an Alcatel-Lucent OmniSwith 9600. I cannot find the option to reboot the switch from the web interface. How else can I reboot the switch without pulling the power? I was able to log into the Telnet portal, but not sure what command can be used there to reboot. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIRC the command to reboot an Omniswitch is simply `reload`

I'd make sure you have saved the config first though (which I believe is `write memory` but it's been years since I've messed with one of these to be honest).

The switches CLI reference guide on Alcatel's site should help as well...but I think the above is accurate.

Comment: In your experience working with Alcatel switches, how often would you need to reboot them? I suspect I am having high latency due to one of the core switches.

Comment: I rarely rebooted one, like once every 6 months at best.  If you are having issues I would check the logs and possibly look at firmware/code upgrades.  Especially if a reboot "fixes it".

Answer (score 2):

try "reload" - can also be used for timing the reboot

Answer (score 1):

Got it. I used "reload" from the CLI over Telnet. Reference: http://www.dinf.ru/Doc_base/Alcatel_omniswitch_commands.pdf

Comment: Probably better suited as just a "Thank you" under my answer. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`reload working no-rollback-timeout` is best to avoid reloading in certified.